# Microsoft's chart controls not printing in an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, charts, controls

We integrated the Microsoft's chart controls in our asp.net web application for reporting.  We were able to use the chart control to draw different charts (bar, column, stacked) on a web page.  The issue came in when we tried to print the chart.  The chart image doesn't always show up on the print preview or the actual print out.  Sometimes all it has is a red x on the corner of the image.  We have tried setting the deleteAfterServicing to false in the web.config file (see below) but the problem still exist.  Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;deleteAfterServicing=false>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that tag to the one below and it should fix the problem as it did for me:

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=memory;timeout=20;deleteAfterServicing=false;" />
```